# Magento Customer Account/Dashboard page

Tags: xml, layout, magento

I want to add more links in the my account page after customers logged in. I dont know whee to edit , i checked the customer related all the layout template files, where i can add those links, Please tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit `app/design/frontend/default/<yourtheme>/layout/customer.xml` for the majority of the links, however other links are also added in `newsletter.xml`, `sales.xml` and others.  Search for the string `customer_account` in *.xml files to track them all down.